# Changing appsetings.json location in .net6

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0, appsettings

i have a solution with 1 project right now. Im doing a webApi in .net core 6. I now need to make an aditional project within the same solution where ill put some shared stuff that will be used once more projects are added.

I had no issues for the most part but moving the appsetings.json file is a bit tricky.

From my understanding, in my main project, these 2 lines of code load up the appsettings file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
```

however once i move the appsetings.json file in another project the first project can no longer access it. Can anyone help me out on this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var diretorio = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\App_Config\\";
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile(diretorio + "appsettings.json",
                       optional: true,
                       reloadOnChange: true);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).